# How to convert an IGeometryCollection into a Polyline

Tags: arcobjects, c#, convert

I am using the CostPathAsPolyline method which returns the Polyline as an IGeometryCollection.  I now need to get this converted back into a polyline.  But it seems to be more complex than just a cast.

Can someone please help me?  I cannot find anything online.

Comment: Is this an ArcGIS related question? Which language are you trying to use?

Comment: This is an ArcObjects question and it is C#.

Comment: Did you want to put that in the question or the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took quite a while to find the correct answer.  Believe it or not, when I told ESRI support that it returned only 1 point she asked what was wrong with that!  This is the final code to actually get a line out of the code following an undocumented process:

```
IGeometryCollection result = distanceComputer.CostPathAsPolyline(points, costSets[0], costSets[1]);
geometry = result.get_Geometry(location);
if (geometry == null)
continue;
if (geometry is IPolycurve)
((IPolycurve)geometry).Densify(0, -1);
Polyline shape = geometry as Polyline;
```

Comment: I had the exactly same problem, but it did not help much in my case. I mean the resulting polyline is in fact only a segment of the true cost path. What is more, mine GemetryCollection contsins a single geometry object too. Did you tackle this issue, or was it working in your case?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just do something like this?

```
IGeometryCollection collection = x.CostPathAsPolyline(y, z, zz);
IPolyline polyline = (IPolyline)collection;
```

Comment: When I do this it runs.  But the object has no length.  When I set it to be returned in a response set, it says there is not enough spatial information to create a geometry (or something like that)  See this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74845/how-to-return-shapes-from-geo-service